# How to ignore print-output in python?

Tags: python, output

I have an import modul XY, when calling it it gives me an output and a return value. But I dont want to have an outpt. How can I ignore it?

```py
#example
import XY as xy

results=xy.return
```

Output:

```
proceeding...
proceeding...
proceeding...
proceeding...
proceeding...
proceeding...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `stdout`:

```
import sys, os

def stopPrint():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

def allowPrint():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```